# How to access a local server from the internet?

Tags: networking, router, internet, ip-address

I have a web server locally, but I would like to be able to access it from the internet. I configured No-IP on the server and created virtual servers in Load Balance, TP-Link and ISP modems. But without the expected result, upon entering it shows me the login page of one of the ISP modems. How should I configure the devices?

This is how they are connected:

*ex. Network Overview*

[image: Network Overview]

*ex. Load Balance Configuration*

[image: Load Balance Configuration - Screenshot]

*ex. Archer C7 Configuration*

[image: Archer C7 Configuration - Screenshot]

*ex. ISP Modem Configuration*

[image: ISP Modem Configuration - Screenshot]

Comment: hi israel - you will get a lot of good help from folks on this site; but I think it will be a difficult question without knowing more about your setup. Just a guess: what computer are you using to connect when you get the login page? Make sure it's not a device that's on your local network, or that may be the reason. You could probably get that to work later if you need it, but for now you should avoid being on your local network while you try connecting over the internet.

Comment: My thought would be that this might be an issue with your Load Balancer settings. You have it set to forward to `192.168.1.10` (which I assume is the internal IP of your server). If this is the case, you may wish to try setting this to the IP of your TP-Link Archer C7 instead (leave the Archer C7 configuration as is).

Comment: Check whether you can actually assign port 80. Your router might actually use that itself and not offer to forward that port (or it might itself become unaccessible)

Comment: What devices are your ISP modems, if they are multifunctional devices(router/modem/AP/WiFi router/JukeBox...) how are they configured? Would love to see IP addresses of your devices ports on the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem begins and ends with port numbers.  Without publishing a chapter here, your best bet is to research the subject on google.  Simply, you are halfway there accessing your modem, likely on port 80.  You are going to have to configure things in such a way that when someone accesses your web server it is on port 80, and your hardware interface be assigned a different port, and using port forwarding your web server gets reached.  Too much for one post to explain, but not too terribly difficult to learn.  This way one IP address can be used for multiple services (65,000+ ports/ip)